# SetProperty: Mandatory attribute property missing

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans

Ok, first some code. Here's the contents of my displayCollection.tag:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" import="com.serco.inquire.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="mgr" required="true" %>
<jsp:useBean id="irc" scope="session" class="com.serco.inquire.irCollection">
<jsp:setProperty name="mgrid" value="${mgr}" />
</jsp:useBean>
${irc.mgrid}
```

Here's the JSP I'm calling it from (myq.jsp):

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*,com.serco.inquire.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="inq" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<inq:displayCollection mgr="Chris Novish" />
```

Here's the java class for irCollection (used in the tag file):

```
package com.serco.inquire;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class irCollection {
public String mgrid;
public irCollection() {
super();
}
public void setMgrid(String datum) {
this.mgrid = datum;
}
public String getMgrid() {
return this.mgrid;
}
}
```

And finally, here's the error I get when i try to run myq.jsp:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/displayCollection.tag(7,2)
>   SetProperty: Mandatory attribute
>   property missing
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.checkAttributes(JspUtil.java:174)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:595)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$SetProperty.accept(Node.java:1150)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:647)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1182)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1789)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:216)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:231)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:577)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:48)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:642)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:660)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:228)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

as far as I can tell, the attribute mgr is set in myq.jsp when it invokes displayCollection.tag, and displayCOllection.tag's only attribute (required) is mgr. so uhm... what do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at Sun's [documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm13.html) on the `jsp:setProperty` tag. The `name` attribute is actually the `id` attribute of the bean declared in `jsp:useBean` - so it should be "`irc`". The `property` attribute is required on `setProperty` and is the actual property you're trying to set.